# How to activate UIPopoverControl on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller, popover

I've seen this feature several times on iPhone Apps (e.g.. At Bat, Garageband, etc.) and I'm just wondering how to activate the feature for iPhone without having to build an own class.

I've seen a simple YouTube video, but following the described steps didn't help much either...

So to be clear, I'd love to have some sample code or a simple explanation on how to port UIPopoverControl to iPhone.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi for PopoverView in iPhone use this bellow Demo with Custom PopUpView..

1. [SNPopup](https://github.com/sonsongithub/PopupView)
2. [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)
3. [SeaGlass](https://github.com/KJoyner/SeaGlass)

Comment: I rather thought of an direct Apple implementation, but I'll try these.

Comment: Yeah, but the the thing is, that it does not look exactly as it does on iPad, like for example in the Facebook iphone App, you know what I mean?

Comment: oh ok now click on this link and see the screen-shot.. https://github.com/sonsongithub/PopupView

Answer (score 2):

You may want [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover). It's not difficult to use.